# I am getting an error when creating functions in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a class that will interact with a postgres database by use of classes, but keep getting an error when creating functions in classes

I have tried using constructor functions with prototypes but still get an error

```
/* eslint linebreak-style: ["error", "windows"] */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const pool = require('../config/config.js');
// user constructor
class User {
  constructor(user) {
    this.username = user.username;
    this.email = user.email;
    this.password = user.password;
    this.role = user.role;
  }
  // save new user in databes
  function createUser() {

  }

  }

module.exports = User;




function createUser(params) {
           ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

This is the error that am getting

Comment: Within a javascript class, you do not use the keyword `function`. Just `createUser() { your code }` or `async createUser() { ... }` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const pool = require('../config/config.js');
// user constructor
class User {
  constructor(user) {
    this.username = user.username;
    this.email = user.email;
    this.password = user.password;
    this.role = user.role;
  }
  // save new user in database
  createUser() {

  }

  }

module.exports = User;
```

As someone else mentioned, this is simply a syntax issue.